# Spring Security and multiple hierarchical roles

Tags: spring-security

I'm working on a spring boot project v2.1.7 and I'm implementing the security with spring security.

In my case I've detected some hierarchies on roles and for this reason my current RoleHierarchy bean is as following

```
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
        return roleHierarchy;
    }
```

Now I need a new role called "BACK_OFFICE" that is less than ADMIN but doesn't have any link with the user role.

How can I represents this situation? I've tried with the following string representation but doens't works.

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_BACK_OFFICE");
    return roleHierarchy;
}
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple role hierarchies by using a newline `\n` to separate them.

```
roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_A > ROLE_B\nROLE_B > ROLE_C");
```

Comment: This is a single hierarchy. I mean, something like "ROLE_A > ROLE_B\nROLE_A > ROLE_C"

Comment: @Gavi it's still the same syntax. Exactly what you mentioned above. "ROLE_A > ROLE_B\nROLE_A > ROLE_C". Are you having issues with that configuration?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any error, but if I write some tests in order to check this kind of hierarchy all the tests are failing. The result is the same as avoid to set any hierarchy. Do you think a github repo as example should be more useful?

Comment: @Gavi a github repo would help with debugging. I want to clarify what the `>` symbol means as well. You can read `>` as "includes". So if your hierarchy is `"ROLE_A > ROLE_B"`, it means every user with "ROLE_A" also has "ROLE_B".